# Android downstream message from GCM "no empty constructor" error

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending a downstream message to Android app from php script. But the receiving Android app crushes and I get "Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class mypackage.myactivity$MyGcmListenerService; no empty constructor" on the logcat. I have an empty constructor though. This is the receiver service:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
        public static final String UPDATE_COORDINATES = "mypackage.newcoordinate";
        LocalBroadcastManager coordintesupdater;

        public MyGcmListenerService() { super(); }

        @Override
        public void onMessageSent(String msgId) {
            Log.i("the damn message " + msgId, "sent");
            super.onMessageSent(msgId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDeletedMessages() {
            super.onDeletedMessages();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSendError(String msgId, String error) {
            super.onSendError(msgId, error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

            String message = data.getString("lat") + ", " + data.getString("lon");

            if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                mIntent.putExtra(UPDATE_COORDINATES, message);
                mIntent.setAction(UPDATE_COORDINATES); //should match the receiver intent filter at the registering
                coordintesupdater.sendBroadcast(mIntent);
            } else {
                Log.i("Received", "empty message");
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my manifest where the service is declared explicitly

```
<service
            android:name=".myactivity$MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I have been researching this the whole evening for hours but I couldn't resolve it. I think the exception is simply broad only to indicate there is a problem, but fails to specify. Can someone point me to the problem?

Comment: Try removing constructor and follow this https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this

```
mypackage.MapActivity$MyGcmListenerService
```

I assume `MyGcmListenerService` is a nested class. Hovewer it is not static, which means it needs an instance of the class `MapActivity` as an implicit parameter to be created.

If you don't access `MapActivity` from `MyGcmListenerService` you can solve the problem by declaring the latter class static:

```
public static class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService
```